# Is there any way to Make the RichEditControl look as a MemoEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, richtextbox

I want to know if there is a way to make the `RichEditControl` as a `MemoEdit` or just like a `TextEdit`.

I will leave a picture to let you know what I need, all I can do at this moment is hide the rulers of the "document". The picture have two controls, the one in the top is the `RichControlEdit`, in the bottom a normal `TextEdit`, who is the look that I need to have in the `RichControlEdit`

[image]

Comment: What do you mean exactly? For example I see both of them are white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [RichEditControl.ActiveViewType](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraRichEditRichEditControl_ActiveViewTypetopic) property to Simple.